# Серверное приложение

Tags: java

У меня есть написанное на java приложение. Оно используя jsop коннектится к html-странице, достает оттуда необходимую информацию и записывает в txt-файл. Потом я импортирую этот txt-файл в Wolfram Mathematica и анализирую информацию, которую он содержит.

Проблема в том, что не всегда есть интернет, да и компьютер постоянно включенным держать глупо. Поэтому хочу сделать так, чтобы такое приложение запускал сервер. Т.е. я помещаю на сервер приложение, и оно на нем работает 24/7 и так же в txt-файл, находящийся на сервере, записывает все. Никаких клиентов пока не нужно.

*Как называется то, что я хочу и на чём (технологии, библиотеки) лучше всего это реализовать?*

Comment: А чем сервер отличается от любого другого компьютера на котором вы запускаете своё приложение?

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как запустить это приложение. Может подскажете, как это можно сделать на виндовс сервере, например(расширение exe)

Comment: Так же как вы это делаете на любом другом компьютере. Берете и запускаете. Если у вас при этом возникают какие-то проблемы(ошибки) их и стоило описать в вопросе.

Comment: Может просто приложение по расписанию запускать?

Answer (score 1):

Арендуйте на каком-либо хостинге виртуальную машину, запускайте свое приложение на ней по расписанию.
Это самый простой ответ "в лоб" на Ваш вопрос.
Но данное решение не является самым дешевым из возможных.

Comment: Что, что на выделенном сервере можно сделать это понятно, вопрос в том, что они от 10$. А вот интересно следующее, если не VPS/VDS а просто хостинг использовать можно в этих целях? Возможно ли на хостинге(тоже виндовс) запустить мое приложение?

Comment: На хостинге до $10 -- сомневаюсь.